# Configuring Magento for Quick Offline Sales

Tags: checkout, sales

I'm trying to setup Magento at an over-the-counter Pharmacy where patients come in with prescriptions and the sale for medications takes place quickly.

Had a look at the Magento POS extensions, but they're really expensive (while I'm looking for a free option).

Is there a way to configure Magento sales in such a way that we have a pre-configured client called "over-the-counter" and just have to:

1. Create a new order
2. Add Products under Items Ordered
3. Submit order (skipping the shipping and payment method)
4. Submit Order
5. Print order

Would really appreciate some help and advise on this, pls.

Answer (score 1):

If in case you just want to skip Shipping & Payment method, I suggest you to go through this article:
http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-payment-and-shipping-method-step

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a comment or an answer, but for comments you don't get reputation :D

Did you look into the backend? There you can do this. If you create all products as virtual, there is no shipping needed, you can change the template to prefill the billing address with anything and I think if there is only one payment method this should be active, if not, change the template here too and you should have what you want.